# Mentioning publication venues for SOP (FALL 2022 CS PhD USA)

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate, statement-of-purpose

I am writing my SOP for CS PhD Programs in the US. I have a few experiences to note down in the SOP and those works have resulted into posters/publications.

**Question:** Is it necessary to mention the "venues" where the work has been publised in the SOP because the list of my works (under review & published) will be mentioned in my CV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worry that you have the wrong idea about the SoP and will lose a chance to use it properly to advance your candidacy. The SoP isn't about what you have done in the past. It isn't about giving extra emphasis or explanation about things in the CV.

The SoP is about the future. What do you plan to do, both in the program you want to enter and thereafter. Make it about the future, not the past. The only time you should really mention the past is in (very) brief phrases that suggest that you will be a success in your future plans. Put past successes in the CV, not the SoP. And, make sure your letters of recommendation also have this forward looking "predictive of success" tone.

If you use the SoP to emphasize the past you are losing an important opportunity. Onward!

Comment: Thank you very much for this advice!